# Combine contents of list member of object collection into single list with linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to replace the foreach loop below with linq?

```
public class Foo
{
    List<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
}

List<Foo> fooList = GetFooList();
List<Bar> allBars = new List<Bar>();

foreach (Foo foo in fooList)
{
    allBars.AddRange(foo.Bars);
}
```

The closest I've gotten is:

```
var temp = fooList.Select(foo => foo.Bars).ToList();
```

which gives a `List<List<Bar>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SelectMany() on foo.Bars

```
allBars.AddRange(fooList.SelectMany(foo => foo.Bars));
```

If allBars variable does not contain anything before AddRange(), you could skip the object creation:

```
List<Bar> allBars = fooList.SelectMany(foo => foo.Bars).ToList();
```

And if you are not going to use fooList somewhere else, you could just write:

```
List<Bar> allBars = GetFooList().SelectMany(foo => foo.Bars).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq's SelectMany is your friend.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx

```
fooList.SelectMany(f => f.Bars)
```

Answer (score 1):

And another variation:

```
List<Foo> fooList = GetFooList();
List<Bar> allBars = fooList.SelectMany(x => x.Bars).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the one more

```
   List<Bar> allBars = fooList.SelectMany(foo => foo.Bars).ToList();
```